# iPhone - how can I record 8 hour video for sleep studies?

Tags: iphone, ios, open-source, video-recording

I would like to try recording sleep with an iPhone, connected to a power source overnight. However, I'm not sure if the default camera is capable of recording videos that long. A colleague suggested using a video codec with very few key frames, just saving the changes between frames.

My questions are twofold - **are there any open source projects that already do long(3+ hours) video recording on iPhone.** How would I extract the file from the iPhone if it is 3 Gb or so in size?

Comment: SO is mainly for programming questions, not really for discussion of "how would you do X".

Comment: You can post your question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/. As a tip, search "iphone as webcam" and "vlc save stream"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance this doesn't really appear to be a programming question...but you hint that you may be looking for open-source code for a video codec.

However I thought I might shed a bit of light on the iPhone itself.

If you're recording at 320p, that averages out to about 15mb per minute. Calculating 8 hours, equals 7.2GB.

To my knowledge, there is no time limit, just the limit of your iPhone empty HD space. However, some people have reported that the video recording stops sometimes, seemingly randomly, during very long recordings.

Comment: I tried recording with an iPod, and it came out to about 75mb per 1 minute :(

Comment: Tried using my Macbook, and it was really good. Photo booth gave me 175 mb per hour, which is suitable for sleep studies, and I don't need to worry about transfering files over